# Play HTML5 video without loading

Tags: html, video, http-headers, mp4

I have a question, When i play a large file with HTML5 player it starts after 5 min or something because he's downloading the video first before playing.
How can i start the video immediately no matter what the size is and let it download while playing?

Looked for 3 days on google but couldn't find anything. 
I hope someone can help me, Thanks

HTTP Headers (Not path to file)

```
Status: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx   
Date:   Fri, 19 Sep 2014 15:38:02 GMT   
Content-Type:   text/html; charset=UTF-8    
Transfer-Encoding:  chunked 
Connection: close   
X-Powered-By:   PHP/5.4.32  
Cache-Control:  no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0  
Cache-Control:  post-check=0, pre-check=0   
Pragma: no-cache    
Content-Encoding:   gzip
```

HTTP Headers (Path to file)

```
GET patt/to/file HTTP/1.1[CRLF]
Host: domain[CRLF]
Connection: close[CRLF]
User-Agent: Web-sniffer/1.1.0 (+http://web-sniffer.net/)[CRLF]
Accept-Encoding: gzip[CRLF]
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,UTF-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7[CRLF]
Cache-Control: no-cache[CRLF]
Accept-Language: de,en;q=0.7,en-us;q=0.3[CRLF]
Referer: http://web-sniffer.net/[CRLF]
```

Need to get it working on the first one

Comment: @hitesh When i go to the full url of the file its working perfect but when i visit the page with my player on it then it doens't work

Comment: @hitesh added output in the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. [Ensure that the `moov` (metadata) is before the `mdat` (audio/video data)](http://multimedia.cx/eggs/improving-qt-faststart/).  This is also called "fast start" or "web optimized".  For example, [Handbrake has a "Web Optimized" checkbox](https://trac.handbrake.fr/wiki/OutputSettings), and [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#Options-3) and [avconv](https://libav.org/avconv.html#MOV_002fMP4_002fISMV) have the output option `-movflags faststart`.
2. Ensure that your web server is reporting the correct Content-Type (video/mp4).
3. [Ensure that your web server is configured to serve byte range requests](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/CreatingVideoforSafarioniPhone/CreatingVideoforSafarioniPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006514-SW6).
4. Ensure that your web server is not applying gzip or deflate compression on top of the compression in the mp4 file.

You can check the headers being sent by your web server using `curl -I http://yoursite/video.mp4` or by going to http://web-sniffer.net/ and entering your mp4 URL there.  The HTTP Response Header should include **Content-Type: video/mp4** and **Accept-Ranges: bytes**, and no **Content-Encoding:**.

Comment: I turned Gzip off, now its the same but only Content-Type: and Content-lenght: is missing from the first one

Answer (score 0):

Try this javascript, which binds the [`play()`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_met_play.asp) function to the [`oncanplay`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_event_canplay.asp) [event](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp) of the [HTML5 video defined by W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp).

```
var myVid = document.getElementById("video1");
myVid.oncanplay = function() {
  myVid.play();
}
```